# Function to round to nearest non-zero decimal place in R (including negatives)

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to round to the nearest non-zero decimal place in R, if rounding to two places yields zero. Expected output would be

```
my_round(12.5624)
> 12.56

my_round(-0.64010)
> -0.64

my_round (0.000026)
> 0.00003

my_round(-0.00072451)
> -0.0007
```

My current thoughts were to round and check whether rounding to two digits yielded zero: if so, I would loop through a sequence of values and iteratively round by X digits until I received a non-zero value. However, this seems unwieldy, inefficient, and is limited to a certain specified number of zero digits at most (in the below code, 10). My attempt (not working properly) is as follows:

```
my_round <- function(x) {
  res <- round(x, 2)
  if (res != 0) {
    return(res)
  }
  for (i in seq(3:10)) {
    res <- round(x, i)
    if (res != 0) {
      return (res)
    }
  }
  return(NA)
}
```

The problem with this is that the output appears as follows

```
my_round(0.00007702)
> 0.0001
```

When instead I am looking for

```
my_round(0.00007702)
> 0.00008
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect for `0.06401`

Comment: @akrun Just 0.06.

Comment: Suppose if the value is `0.600034` do you return 0.60.  Sorry, just tryng to understand the pattern you expect

Comment: @akrun Correct, anything for which the output of `round(x, 2)` is non-zero, just take that output. Otherwise I'm looking for rounded to the nearest non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could change the function to

```
my_round <- function(x)  {
  x1 <- round(x, 2)
  if(round(x, 2) == 0) {
    n1 <- stringr::str_locate(x, "[^-0.]")[1] -  str_locate(x, fixed("."))[1]
    print(n1)
    x1 <- round(x, n1)
  
  }
  return(x1)

  
  }
```

-testing

```
> my_round(12.5624)
[1] 12.56
> my_round(-0.64010)
[1] -0.64
> my_round(0.000026)
[1] 5
[1] 0.00003
> my_round(-0.00072451)
[1] 4
[1] -0.0007
> my_round(0.00007702)
[1] 5
[1] 0.00008
```

Comment: note that this requires the stringr package

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
my_round = function(x, n=2) {
  max(abs(round(x, n)), abs(signif(x, 1))) * sign(x)
  }

my_round(12.5624)
# [1] 12.6
my_round(-0.64010)
# [1] -0.64
my_round (0.000025)
# [1] 2e-05
my_round(-0.00072451)
# [1] -7e-04
my_round(0.00007702)
# [1] 8e-05
```

Note that `my_round(0.000025)` *should* give `2e-05`, according to the standard rule of "round half to even" (see `?round` for an explanation of this rounding rule).